# How can I print users input name as he enters in the input box

Tags: javascript

```js
function.getElementById("a")
{
    var input= document.getElementById("a")
    console.log("input")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
  <div class="a">
    <input id="a" placeholder="enter here..." >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want  to print the name of user as same he enters in the input box.

Comment: `function.getElementById("a")` is invalid syntax. Familiarize yourself with the [DOM API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and with [events](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events). Use the [`input` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event).

Comment: try `console.log(input.value)` instead of `console.log("input")` (which is logging the literal string `"input"`). Then you just need to trigger it when the input value changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. You need to add an event listener to a variable which represents the input element. The event it listens for is the *input* event. When any input happens the function fires which logs the value of the input element to the console.

```js
const input= document.querySelector("#a")

input.addEventListener('input', function(event){
  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input id="a" placeholder="enter here..." >
```

Answer (score 0):

use event keyup

```js
addEventListener('keyup',test)

function test(){

let x = document.getElementById('a').value
console.log(x)



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
  <div class="a">
    <input id="a" placeholder="enter here..." >
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```